# Display Successful Message Notifications at Sweetalert

Tags: javascript, php

I want to display the message successfully deleting data with Sweetalert, and the beginning of the script:

```
 <a href="delete.php?&id=<?php echo $r['id']; ?>" class="delete-link">Delete</a>
```

Javascript :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.delete-link').on('click', function() {
        var getLink = $(this).attr('href');
        swal({
            title: 'Alert',
            text: 'Delete?',
            html: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#d9534f',
            showCancelButton: true,
        }, function() {
            window.location.href = getLink
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

the data has been successfully deleted, but the way you want to display the data message has been deleted like this, where is it put in?

```
swal("Success!", "Successfully Deleted Data!", "success");
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for the sweet alert.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.delete-link').on('click',function(){
        var getLink = $(this).attr('href');
        swal({
          title: "Are you sure?",
          text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
          type: "warning",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
          confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
          cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
          closeOnConfirm: false,
          closeOnCancel: false
        },
        function(isConfirm) {
          if (isConfirm) {
            $.ajax({
            url: getLink,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'
            })
            .done(function(data){
                console.log(data);
                swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
            })
            .fail(function(){
                swal("Deleted_Error", "Error while deleting. :)", "error");
            });

          } else {
            swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
          }
        });
    });
});
```

[See here for the example for the Sweetalert](https://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-sweetalert/)

Comment: I update code according to what i understand. Hope it will help you.